# Firefox firing onchange events after tab restore

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

Firefox is firing onchange events in my webapp after tab restore.

When reloading the same URL in Firefox there is no problem, no onchange events get fired on page load, all changed values since last visit are displayed correctly.

But when reopening the same page with the same URL, after closing Firefox and reopening the page with "restored tabs" (from the Firefox option "show my windows and tabs from last time") then it is firing onchange events for all values that have been changed since last visit.

Actual workflow ot reproduce the problem:

1. My update events are in background (JavaScript/AJAX) and are fired
   with onchange events;
2. Firefox setting "show my windows and tabs from last time" enabled;
3. Change some values in my page (select fields);
4. Close Firefox;
5. Open the same URL on another browser or computer, and change some values;
6. Reopen Firefox, select the tab with the page on it, it reloads and fires     onchange events again for all changed values since last visit.

Tried to reproduce this behaviour with completely different pages (not created by me and using other script libraries and stuff) and the result is the same, it is always firing the onchange events.

Chrome is not doing this with the "restore tabs" option.

Why is it firing onchange events? How can I prevent it?

Comment: can I use firefox on the other computer at step 5?

Comment: yes, just change the values of the content (select) somewhere else, other computer with any browser or different browser on same computer. Then start firefox again and click on the tab to 'restore' (not exactly reload) the page ... select will fire onchange event.

Comment: maybe you could add 2 inputs type=hidden or javascript variables and set the browser used at loading and the browser used when the change was made to the select. And then cancel the onchange event if the 2 values are not identical.

Comment: Yes of course that is correct,  I could figure out workarounds with timestamp of last updates or similar solutions. But I want to know 'why' firefox is doing that, if it is normal (and why different then chrome) and if it can be prevented with for example a much easier solution such as no-cache settings or similar settings for web pages. I'm not a big fan of rebuilding web apps because of some strange behaviour of 1 browser used with a specific setting ...

Comment: you could post about it on bugzilla, maybe you would have more success

Comment: Firefox's Session Restore AFAI understand reloads the DOM and then changes it according to the [saved data from form elements](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Session_Restore#Data_to_be_saved). This is likely what triggers the `onchange` event. I believe this bug report is very similar to what you are describing: [Bug 464691 - Restoring the session overwrites form data with updated defaults](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=464691). Unfortunately I am not sure what to do about it, maybe try adding CSRF tokens?

Comment: according to http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.check_doc_frequency you can try setting `browser.cache.check_doc_frequency = 2` in `about:config` to `always load the page from cache` (and '`browser.cache.disk.enable` or `browser.cache.memory.enable` must be set to true for this preference to work as mentioned'). By default `check_doc_frequency` is set to `3` meaning: 'Check for a new version when the page is out of date.' But this might only fix FF-browsers you control.. Also see https://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/10/15/two-important-differences-between-firefox-and-ie-caching/

Comment: Could you fiddle something to track it? The Niklas comment  was what I was thinking about.
The dispatched event  insn't different from a user event?

Comment: Are you able to provide us some code !!! because it could be from server side or check you 'addEventListener() ' because it could adding another listener to your function and it runs only on firefox.  so try to remove Listener
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: Can't provide code but you can try this with any webapp, I tried with other webapps also and the result was the same, a restored tab will fire onchange events for change values, only in FF I found this behaviour.

Comment: Maybe you could compare the both events? The human triggered one and the other while restoring tabs.

Comment: Short answer: you DON'T. Do not validate your input with Javascript. What if I open the console and manually create a change event with malicious code? Will your server crash? Create proper backend checks and you will not have to worry about browser-specific behaviour.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand what are you saying: Change events are fired ALWAYS by only restarting firefox or ONLY if, fields in reloaded pages has different default values than ones it had first time the page was loaded?

Comment: change events fired ONLY when restoring tab (not on page reload) AND ONLY when values are different then last values (before browser close)

Comment: i would inspect the properties of the actual change event object to see if i could find a smoking gun that differentiates between a user-caused change and a mere restore change.

Comment: post in bugzilla.. its the right way

Comment: If you can put some sample code to reproduce the problem then more people can try and will be easy to look into problem.

Comment: On a separate note, if this is not reproducible in Chrome, then there are far greater chances that it is a Firefox specific problem, so as said by many - post it in Bugzilla as well. However, here people can try to get you a fix.

Answer (score 2):

A few suggestions on how to deal with this depending on the wanted result. Note that this is tested on my machine, behaviors may vary. 
They way it seems to work is that Firefox tries to restore data that was entered by user. So it modifies the page, triggering the `change` `event`. This event is slighlty different than the one triggered by the user. It is a `UIEvent` while the user triggered one is a straight `Event`. And this Event is `cancelable` and triggered before the `window load` event. So this gives a couple of ways to deal with this. I'll take a select element for example.

If you want the select to keep value entered before window closing, but not trigger the onchange event, you can set the onchange call on the `window.onload`. Like this:

```
window.onload = function(){
     element.onchange = function(){
```

Since the setting of the `select` occurs before `onload`, this specific change won't trigger your `onchange` function.

Other way would be to target behaviors you don't to trigger by putting a condition validating if the element is cancelable or not. If it's `cancelable`, it means it's called from a restore session and won't trigger what's inside. Like this:

```
element.onchange = function(e){
         if(e.cancelable == true){
```

Other way, to clear out all data would be to set a `document.onchange` event and reload the page if the event is `cancelable`. Like this:

```
 document.onchange = function(e){
        if(e.cancelable == true){
            window.location = window.location
             }
      }
```

Of course you need to make sure you don't have any other cancelable change event called in your page.

EDIT:

To clarify order of events fired, see this jsfiddle, not in iframes, iframes seems to behave differently, so if you have iframes, it may be a bit more complicated. But without iframe, you'll see how the different events are triggered depending on your interactions:

```
 document.onchange = function (e) {
      //this will be triggered on restore before the window load event           
      alert('restore onchange called, e.cancelable = ' + e.cancelable)
 }


 window.onload = function (e) {
     //You'll see that on restore, this will be triggered but after page has been updated
     alert('window load called')
     document.onchange = function () {
         //This onchange will be called normally, not on restore
         alert('after onload change, e.cancelable = ' + e.cancelable)
     }

 }
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nozp9uhk/6/show/

Comment: so far an answer with a little more insight. I have tried the 2nd suggestion, with the "cancelable" property, it works to prevent the onchange event, but now the values are not changed. So ... I would like the values to be updated (just like a page reload would do) without triggering the onchange event ....

Comment: if you want the values to be changed but the onchange not triggered, I think the best solution is the first one where you assign the onchange after window load. SInce the restore change event is triggered before window load it won't trigger the onchange assigned after onload event.

Comment: but then the page will not work anymore as it was designed to do ? no onchange events will work anymore after tab restore ...

Comment: The window.load event will still be triggered on a restore, but it'll be triggered after you page has been updated with cache data. So your onchange will be assigned and will trigger normally, just not before all restore events have already occured. Which seems to be your expected result and which is consistent with other browser behaviors also.

Comment: the onchange event is then indeed after the window onload and do not get triggered, but the values are not refreshed. Probably because the page was never closed and it keeps form values.  But it should behave just like the browser/page is closed and opened again without "tab restore". Like opening browser again and navigating to that page, getting the latest results, without triggering onchange :)

Comment: OK, then I'm not quite clear with the result you expect. Maybe it's not possible in your specific case, but the way it works, I don't see what cases wouldn't be supported, at least to give a cross browser consistent result. This specific event is simply something added, that could even be useful, it doesn't seem like something interfering with anything.

Comment: I will check it next week but I assume this doesn't have the same result als the tab restore in chrome...

Answer (score -1):

Firefox is caching your files when you load the page, so when you restore the tab, the differences between your cached values and the new ones may be firing onchange events.

Try to clear the cache when restoring the tab. I see two ways to do this :

Call `window.location.reload(true)` to reload the current page

or

Change the name of the JavaScript file that initializes the onchange events for this :

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="yourscript.js?n=1"></script>
```

This (?n=1) will force Firefox to load a new copy of the file "yourscript.js"